Upload image does not showing
Shopify image upload then get errors. I have no idea how to get these errors.
upload image after that return value in resource url my uploaded image path not working. image URL generated but when I am this URL in the browser then shows an error This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
so please let me know any solution to this.
I shared my screenshot to get an error related.
https://prnt.sc/eOOL0a_mdQqt

Don't post error as screenshot. Copy & paste into your question.

just i said to how resolved this error. if you have any idea.
